# Neteeza in Aginity "Call Update" Procedure times out

Tags: mysql

I work with a company on creating tables from data extracted by querying a large database of healthcare claims.

Aginity and Neteeza are programs that I use. When my time frame is short (1 month) the following command runs fine: Call Update_Stars_Claims()
However, when the time frame is extended to 12 months, this procedure takes a very long time (up to 10 hours) and eventually times out.

It's frustrating because everything worked fine last year when the time period for the claims was 11 months. It took a long time but completed.

I tried adjusting time out period from 3600 to 0. THat did not change the situation.

My information is as follows. 
Workbench:  Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics 4.4.2183.656 (MSI) (3/31/2015)
OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
DBMS Version:   Release 7.2.1.4-P3 [Build 105]
Driver Used:    Netezza ODBC
Driver Signature:   {NetezzaSQL}
NetezzaSQL ODBC Version:    7.2.0.43166
OleDb Version:  Unknown or not installed

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. It seems that another user is using the same Sandbox server as me. This resulted in slowing the process for me and total stoppage for the other user.

Comment: The process of finding this answer was frustrating but it worked out in the end.